# Popping Fragment from backstack on BACK key press

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am adding a Fragment and transaction is committed to the back stack using the following code:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(id, fragment, "TAG").addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Now when is press the BACK key. Activity is getting finished. But I just want to remove the fragment.

Should I manually handle the BACK key press and do the task of popping backstack or is there any way I can make activity to handle this automatically.

Comment: Same here. did you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

I found one reason for why it may happen:

If you are using app.Activity but making transactions with SupportFragmentManager, or using support.Activity and making transactions with FragmentManager, it seems that the activity ignores the fragments back-stack.

The usage should be consistent, support or normal.